# Is there a way to format code in Eclipse's compare tool? Ignoring whitespace isn't enough

Tags: eclipse, version-control, formatting, compare

When using the compare tool, Eclipse shows this

```
void foo() {
    //...
}
```

as different from this

```
void foo()
{
    //...
}
```

which while technically correct is annoying when comparing two versions of files that have different formatting. **Is there a way to apply the current formatting to the compare view?** Even if it's a different style than either of the two things being compared it would at least give a nice base for finding the "actual" differences in the code.

The only plugin I have found is [this](http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/2007/08/18/eclipse-cvs-compare/) but it doesn't work with my Eclipse (Luna), probably because it was made for a much older version.

---

As an aside, another useful thing and perhaps easier would be to ignore new line characters and tabs, of course this would show

```
foobar
```

and

```
foo
bar
```

as the same but it's better than nothing.